# Which PHP MVC project is most similar to ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

In regards to action heplers, routes, etc...

I look forward to answers from people who've worked with both ASP.NET MVC and some PHP MVC project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember reading somewhere a while back that [Prado](http://www.pradosoft.com/) was very close to ASP.NET MVC but i've not used it myself so cannot confirm beyond that.

Comment: Prado is the only ASP.NET like PHP framework. I'm not even sure why someone suggested Yii which is nothing like it.

Comment: Prado looks nice. I'll check it out.